# PCI Type II Interface is what, exactly?

Tags: pci

I have a D-Link Rangebooster N 650 Desktop (wireless) Adapter (M No. DWA-547) sitting on my desk. It says it uses a **PCI Type II Interface.** I'm wondering what exactly this is?

Is it the old school PCI slots that have been around forever? Is it one of the PCI Express slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wonderful Wiki states:

> Technical details of Mini PCI
>   Mini PCI cards have a 2 W maximum power consumption, which also limits the functionality that can be implemented in this form factor. They also are required to support the CLKRUN# PCI signal used to start and stop the PCI clock for power management purposes.
>   There are three card form factors: Type I, **Type II**, and Type III cards. The card connector used for each type include: **Type I and II use a 100-pin stacking connector**, while Type III uses a 124-pin edge connector, i.e. the connector for Types I and II differs from that for Type III, where the connector is on the edge of a card, like with a SO-DIMM. Type II cards have RJ11 and RJ45 mounted connectors. These cards must be located at the edge of the computer or docking station so that the RJ11 and RJ45 ports can be mounted for external access.

PCI-E is an updated/faster version of the PCI. see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)

Comment: Type II cards are a little thicker than Type I cans. This allowed extra space needed for microdrives.

Comment: same slot though, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct